# Azure Devops - trigger pipeline on Pull Request but not Push?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have a ADO git repo with a YAML-based build pipeline that builds a docker image, runs some tests using Docker Compose, and then pushes the image and a helm chart to an ACR.

I'd like the have the build/test part run on PRs too. I have created a second pipeline that's just the first half of the normal build, and assigned it as a Build Validation pipeline for a branch.

However, I don't seem to be able to get the triggers right. If I have `trigger: none` in the test pipeline, it never triggers. If I have branch names, it is also run on merge alongside the normal build pipeline. How is this supposed to work? The docs define all the individual parts, but not really how they are expected to interact!

Am I supposed to have a multistage pipeline and use that somehow for the validation? (it's just 4 Steps in one Job in one Stage currently).

I am hoping to avoid building the same image too many times, or storing untested images anywhere outside the build agent.

Comment: the `trigger: none` shouldn't affect the Build Validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make it work with the following configuration:

**In my YAML pipeline**, I set the `trigger: none`.

**In branch policies of a branch**, I create a build validation with automatic trigger:
[image]

Then I create a pull request to that branch, and the pipeline runs automatically:
[image]

There are two possible mistakes:

1. The "Manual" trigger is selected in build validation, so that the pipeline needs to be run manually rather than triggered automatically.
2. The branch with branch policy set should be the same branch as the target branch of pull request.

Comment: I don't know what I missed the first time, but this is now working as expected for me. Thanks for the detailed description!
(I think it might have been setting the default branch to the one that I usually merge PRs into, so that the pipeline definition is definitely the current one)